# Android ViewPager setCurrentItem not loading the requested page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to move to the specified page in viewPager.

My code is -

```
    if(isFirstCall) {
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), pageId);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPagePosition);
        }
    });

    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        private static final float thresholdOffset = 0.5f;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);


            if (checkDirection) {

                mPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

                if (thresholdOffset > positionOffset) {
                    checkDirection = false;

                    // Call service to get next page position 
                } else {
                    checkDirection = false;

                    // Call service to get prev page position 
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);

            if ((scrollStarted == false) && (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) ) {
                scrollStarted = true;
                checkDirection = true;
            } else {
                scrollStarted = false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }
    });
```

When I try to update the currentPagePosition variable, the viewPager hangs and does not move to the specified page immediately. (It is observed that, after approximately 10-15 mins the specified page is called.)

Whereas, if I don't modify the value of currentPagePosition variable, everything works fine (but it moves to a different page as I get a wrong value).

I am unable to understand what is going wrong.

Please help..

Observation -

My observation is that - onPageScrollStateChanged method does not get called with state = 1. Resulting in failure of condition in onPageScrolled. So the next page is not called. I don't have any idea why onPageScrollStateChanged is not getting called for state 'SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING'.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPagePosition);
    }
});
```

into

```
mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPagePosition);
mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You should run UI change related code into the main UI thread.

Comment: This did not help.

Comment: did you call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I get page list from server after next / prev page slide. I did not call notifyDataSetChanged() because my data array is global and once I get the response from server, the array gets modified.

Comment: if your server delays to reply then your call also delays. so what is your expected behaviour?

Comment: There is no problem in server response time. My observation is that - onPageScrollStateChanged method does not get called with state = 1. Resulting in failure of condition in onPageScrolled. So the next page is not called. I don't have any idea why onPageScrollStateChanged is not getting called for state 'SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING'.